# Include android core layout in xml

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

The thing is, if you want to include any layout inside other layout, you simply must do:

```
<include layout="@layout/your_layout"/>
```

But, if you would like to include one of android's core layout as `simple_list_item_2`, how would this be done?

**UPDATE 1 --**

Using the solution given:

```
<include layout="@android:layout/simple_list_item_2"/>
```

Now It makes me have another question.

I'v got an activity that calls to another ListActivity. I need to manage if we are on phone or tablet, this way, if we are on phone only the ListActivity will be shown, but if we are on tablet, the ListActivity and a DetailFragment will be shown.

In my ListActivity, I do this:

```
public PlacesCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, R.layout.THE_LAYOUT, c, 0);

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.THE_LAYOUT, parent, false);
        //...

        return view;
    }
    //...
```

This is the reason why I made the first question. I need to use the `simple_list_item_2` to contain the list's elements. But depending if we are on phone or tablet, I must show only the list, or the list and the detail.

I don't know well how to manage this, so the first thing that I've done is create a layout that only includes the `simple_list_item_2` for the phone, and create another layout with the same name, but keeped in the layout-large folder, which also includes the `simple_list_item_2` but also has a framelayout to set there the DetailFragment.

This layout is called list_layout, and inside of it is the `simple_list_item_2`:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include 
        android:id="@+id/list_simple"
        layout="@android:layout/simple_list_item_2" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>  
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, my doubt is... Can I do this? In the java code snippet above, could a make reference to the layout included inside instead of to the entire layout??

Comment: Use fragments see this sample http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<include 
    layout="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: Ok, now let's supposse this: I've got a layout called `list_layout` and inside this I have done the include to include the `simple_list_item_2`. Now, in the activity, I want to set as it's layout, the `simple_list_item_2` included inside the layout, so... this can be done?

Comment: @masmic_87 I don't get you. Can u explain?